# Is a Disk Encryption Password distinct from the root password?

Tags: mount, login, password, encryption, data-recovery

Sooo... I recently had to reset my password on ubuntu 16.04 and I apparently made a typo because I am no longer able to get in.

Brute forcing, etc. is infeasible because the password was around 33 characters long and had a bunch of special characters and numbers and whatnot.

My disk was encrypted from when I set up the OS however, and historically, when I have tried to change my password (admin) I have been able to log in with the new password, but unable to access my files because of the encryption element. Changing my password back has always resolved this.

My question is that if I take my disk out of my computer and connect it to a different system and try to mount it as a regular external file system, will I be able to access its contents with the "*original* root password"? (i.e. the one used to encrypt the file system originally)

Or should I just give up hope and yeet myself off of a bridge? (kidding)

Thoughts?

Comment: Only supported releases of Ubuntu (*standard support*) are on-topic for this site.  Ubuntu 14.04 LTS is EOL (*end-of-life*) thus off-topic, and Ubuntu 14.04 ESM is in extended support and only supported by Canonical via Ubuntu Advantage thus also off-topic here.  Refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades
https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2019/05/02/ubuntu-14-04-trusty-tahr-reached-end-of-life-on-april-25-2019-esm-available/

Comment: The answer to your title will likely depend on the encryption used...  Different releases of Ubuntu used different encryption by default, but for most the encryption key is completely different to root password (root password is **not** set on a default Ubuntu install; it's *undefined* so having an encryption key *undefined* makes no sense at all!)

Comment: Phew! I know your answer isnt meant to be definitive but I'll take it as a ray of hope.

I corrected my system version in my original question as well. Thanks!